# Need help to select radio button in Chrome (Part II) using Excel VBA Selenium Basic

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm struggling once more trying to select a radio button in Chrome (v 75.0.3770.100) using Selenium Basic ChromeDriver (v 75.0.3770.140) in Excel (2013) VBE. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class=radio-wrap>
<input id="shipToSelect" type="radio" class="radio" 
name="soldToShipToselection" value="SH" ng-click="radioClicked($event)">
<label for="shipToSelect" class="radio-label">
<i></i>
<span>Ship-to</span>
</label>
</div>
```

I've tried unsuccessfully with the below:

```
obj.FindElementByCss("div.radio-wrap>input.radio[id$='radio']").Click
obj.FindElementByName("soldToShipToselection").Click
obj.FindElementById("shipToSelect").Click
obj.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='radio-wrap']/input[.,(@id,'shipToSelect')]").Click
```

Comment: Is the radio button readily available to be clicked ? If not, then you can wait for the element to be clickable.

Comment: "VBE" stands for "Visual Basic Editor" and is the name of the VBA IDE. The language is "VBA", aka "Visual Basic for Applications".

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, I've corrected it and my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the *radio button* associated with the text as **Ship-to** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByCss("label[for='shipToSelect']").Click
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//label[@for='shipToSelect']").Click
  ```

**Note**: As it is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element you need to induce a waiter for the *element to be clickable*

---

### Update

As an alternative, you can try either of the folloing *Locator Strategies*:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByCss("input.radio#shipToSelect[name='soldToShipToselection']").Click
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='radio' and @id='shipToSelect'][@name='soldToShipToselection']").Click
  ```

Comment: even after waiting till the Chrome isn't busy, it still throws a Run-time error 7: NoSuchElementError
Element not found for Css=label[for='shipToSelect']

is there any way to use cssSelector or xpath to click on this element? since it's the actual radio button when inspecting

 <input id="shipToSelect" type="radio" class="radio" 
name="soldToShipToselection" value="SH" ng-click="radioClicked($event)">

Comment: Doesn't the locators in my answer helps you when used along with wait?

Comment: Run-time error 7: NoSuchElementError Element not found for Css=label[for='shipToSelect']

Comment: `NoSuchElementError` of coarse you need to wait as the element is dynamic element.

Comment: yes but even when in the VBE debug mode and Chrome window is completely idle but still throws an error when executing the line

Comment: the radio buttons are within li and ul tags, not sure if this has to do with it

Comment: Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Hi DebanjanB my bad seems the preceding code opened a new tab in the chrome where these elements are located. Just got to learn how to switch between tabs first (there should be some old posts on this) then those selector strategies should work :)

Comment: After I used switchtonextwindow then the solutions provided worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `Xpath` to click on radio button.Use `Explicit` wait before interacting the element.

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='radio-wrap']/input[@id='shipToSelect']").Click
```

Comment: this worked, i had to switchtonextwindow first since the previous line opened a new Chrome tab. Thanks!